# Elasticsearch match against filter only

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

We have a multi-tenant index and need to perform queries against the index for a single tenant only. Basically, for all documents that match the filter, return any documents that match the following query, but do not include documents that only match the filter.

For example, say we have a list of documents document like so:

```
{ _id: 1, account_id: 1, name: "Foo" }
{ _id: 2, account_id: 2, name: "Bar" }
{ _id: 3, account_id: 2, name: "Foo" }
```

I thought this query would work but it doesn't:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": { "term": { "account_id": 2 } },
    "should": [
      { "match": { "name": "Foo" }
    ]
  }
}
```

It returns both documents matching `account_id: 2`:

```
{ _id: 3, account_id: 2, name: "Foo", score: 1.111 }
{ _id: 2, account_id: 2, name: "Bar", score: 0.0 }
```

What I really want is it just to return document `_id: 3`, which is basically "Of all documents where account_id is equal to 2, return only the ones whose names match Foo".

How can I accomplish this with ES 6.2? The caveat is that the number of `should` and `must` match conditions are not always known and I really want to avoid using `minimum_should_match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: simply replace `should` by `must`:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": { "term": { "account_id": 2 } },
    "must": [
      { "match": { "name": "Foo" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We had multiple fields that _could_ match, and for this particular search I just found `multi_match` so I think we are going to go with `must: { multi_match: {} }`.